# Java 1.5 Is it always possible to use the wrapper class instead of the primitive?

Tags: java, wrapper

Time ago we built our DTO classes with int fields, and after weeks of development using them, I've been asked to change the type of those fields from int to Integer.
I thought that it was not possible to simply change the type in the declaration, but after a couple of modifications there hasn't been any compilation error.
Is it that simple?

Comment: More or less - one important difference is that an `Integer` can be null, an `int` can't. Similarly, the default value for an `Integer` is `null` whereas the default value for an `int` is `0`.

Comment: [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) is what's making it easy for you.

Comment: @assylias: Yes, that's one of the main reasons they want to change the type.

Comment: Check either for compare with == between the primitive types this is only true when the range is in cache region

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is because of autoboxing. Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html.

Howver, be aware of null pointer exceptions that can be caused by implicitly changing a Integer object to int if the Integer object is null.

Answer (score 1):

Java 5 provides Autoboxing/Unboxing, which is why you are not seeing any compilation issues.

The conversion of int (primitive data type) to Integer is called Autoboxing, and the reverse is called Unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather not do this. There are situations where the box types are inferior to the primitive (e.g. since they are objects, you can put them in collections), but replacing all primitives with their box types seldom pays out. As others already mentioned, you have to check for null values. Also note that it is very easy to oversee the creation of *new* objects as well.